# jQuery upload that will resize the image with some resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a form input file, and when we upload an image, it will resize the image 2 times.  First the original image will resize to square resolution(100x100), and second the original image will resize to landscape resolution(1000x500).  After upload the square resolution will go to folder square and landscape will go for folder landscape.

So the original image won't be saved to the database, but the resized images will.  Do you think a jQuery plugin for my case exists?

Comment: can you upload your code or a fiddle?

Comment: lol why i got downvote? i just need a refference if its legit or not guys. if not then i wont think about that case anymore, i still learning so need a little help.

Comment: Downvotes are because requests for libraries, plugins, etc. are off-topic.

Comment: @TonyHinkle - that was a nice way of saying it.

Comment: @Roysh its still just my imagination, case for my test honestly, if there is jquery plugin fot my case please help me, if i must create the jquery manually then its okay.

Comment: I'm no expert, but to me it sounds like a node.js thing. I suppose if you created a database and had a square table and a landscape table, you could get jQuery to work if you could store the image in SQL...

Comment: @James McDowell hmm, in my case is for portfolio website honestly. i have an image(lets say its imageA). the imageA will be use in portfolio list(where all my portfolio will be show) and it have to be with square resolution. and when go to detail portfolio imageA will go to landscape resolution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off topic because *[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*

Comment: @Tony Hinkle oh so how i close this thread. my bad

Comment: @vandi Under the tags for the question, there is a "delete" link.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript/Jquery is not the right choice there.

Javascript/Jquery work client side: they operate on users pc and not on your server. Maybe there are some plugins capable of resizing images, but surely you won't be able to store them in different folders using Javascript/Jquery

Such an operation must be done on your server, with a sever side language like PHP, NodeJS (still uses Javascript language), Java or many others.

The answer is based on the language off your choice, so i can't give a general one